# Haskell type class instance syntax

Tags: haskell

Suppose i have a datatype `MayFail` defined as following

```
data MayFail e a = Error e | Result a
    deriving (Show)
```

So it's either a result or an error. I now want to write a `Functor` for it but this is where it gets confusing.

`MayFail` has two types, either `e` or `a`. So why do I have to write the functor as follows

```
instance Functor (MayFail e) where
  fmap _ (Error e)  = Error e
  fmap f (Result x) = Result (f x)
```

and not `instance Functor (MayFail e a) where`?

What is the syntactic rule behind this?

Comment: There's no "syntactic rule", it's in fact semantic. You don't have `instance Functor (Maybe a)`, instead it's `instance Functor Maybe`. A Functor has to be parametrised by another type, that is it is a "type level function" that takes one "concrete type" and produces another. `MayFail e` has this property, but `MayFail e a` doesn't.

Answer (score 9):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I assume you're asking why you have to use `e` in `instance Functor (MayFail e)` instead of just writing `instance Functor MayFail`.

This is because `Functor` takes a type parameter of kind `Type -> Type`, and `MayFail` on its own would have kind `Type -> Type -> Type`. (Using `MayFail e a` would also be wrong, as its kind is just `Type`.)

Answer (score 3):

`MayFail :: Type -> Type -> Type` is not a functor, but a bifunctor:

```
-- somewhat simplified definition
class Bifunctor p where
    -- p :: Type -> Type -> Type
    bimap :: (a -> c) -> (c -> d) -> p a b -> p c d

instance Bifunctor MayFail where
    bimap f _ (Error e) = Error (f e)
    bimap _ g (Result x) = Result (g x)
```

But, for any fixed error type `e`, the result of the partial application `MayFail e :: Type -> Type` is a functor:

```
instance Functor (MayFail e) where
    fmap _ (Error e) = Error e
    fmap f (Result x) = Result (f x)
    -- Or, using the Bifunctor instance,
    -- fmap = bimap id
```

In some sense, a bifunctor is a mapping of types to functors.

Comment: Please don't use `*` anymore. It is deprecated. It should instead be called `Type`, as imported from `Data.Kind`.

Comment: @HTNW I'll change it, but can you provide a citation for it *really* being deprecated (or at least, when `StarIsType` will default to off)?

Comment: The manual says it is ["not recommended"](https://mpickering.github.io/ghc-docs/build-html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-StarIsType). The reason `StarIsType` even exists is because [a proposal](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/ea2696fe2f7bcf04d29a3848fc90e7395a5cce4d/proposals/0030-remove-star-kind.rst) was accepted to make `*` stop existing. The plan is long range: the complete removal of `*` is not to come for almost a decade yet.

Answer (score 1):

The `Functor` class is defined as

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

That is, the type constructor `f` must accept a single type argument (otherwise `f a` and `f b` in the type signature of `fmap` would be invalid).

Formally this means `f` must have kind `Type -> Type` (also known as `* -> *` in older versions of GHC).

This is different from e.g. `Eq` or `Show`, which look like this (simplified):

```
class Eq a where
    (==) :: a -> a -> Bool

class Show a where
    show :: a -> String
```

Here the parameter `a` is used as a type itself.

Your type, `data MayFail e a`, has two parameters. If we were to plug just `MayFail` into the `Functor` definition, as in

```
instance Functor MayFail where ...
```

this would implicitly declare `fmap` as

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> MayFail a -> MayFail b
```

which is a kind error: `MayFail a` is not a type because `MayFail` takes two arguments.

Similarly, if we tried

```
instance Functor (MayFail x y) where ...
```

then `fmap` would end up having the type

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> MayFail x y a -> MayFail x y b
```

which is also a kind error: `MayFail` only takes two arguments, not three.

The only way to form a sensible type signature is to set `f = MayFail e`, because then `f a` becomes `MayFail e a` (and `f b` becomes `MayFail e b`), which is well-formed.